# Add range to a new list of object within the same command / line

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'm trying to add a range of a list of objects to a new list, but I'm getting the following message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type "void" to "System.Collections.Generic.List"

Here is what I'm trying:

```
Detalhes = new List<DetalhesExcel>() {
    new DetalhesExcel()
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = "Representante",
        Coluna2 = "ValorRepasse",
        Coluna3 = "KmRepasse"
    }
}.AddRange(ocorrencias.Where(x => x.Conclusao != "PRÓPRIO")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Representante)
    .Select(x => new DetalhesExcel
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = x.First().Representante,
        Coluna2 = x.Sum(y => y.ValorRepasse).ToString(),
        Coluna3 = x.Sum(y => y.KmRepasse).ToString()
    }).ToList())
```

What do I need to do?

---

DetalhesExcel Class:

```
public class DetalhesExcel
{
    public int NumColunaInicial { get; set; }
    public string Coluna1 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna2 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna3 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna4 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: please put yor DetalhesExcel class on the code

Comment: @JoãoPauloAmorim `DetalhesExcel` class structure has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @Sumitraj i was just trying to recreate it here, sorry

Comment: @joão-paulo-amorim Ok, I've updated it with the class.

Comment: `.AddRange` needs to be called separately since it returns `void`. Try `Concat` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is something like this

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Ocorrencia> ocorrencias = new List<Ocorrencia>() {
            new Ocorrencia() {
                Conclusao = "teste",
                KmRepasse = 1,
                Representante = "um",
                ValorRepasse = 2
            }
        };



        var Detalhes = new List<DetalhesExcel>() {
                new DetalhesExcel()
                {
                    NumColunaInicial = 23,
                    Coluna1 = "Representante",
                    Coluna2 = "ValorRepasse",
                    Coluna3 = "KmRepasse"
                }
            }.Concat(ocorrencias.Where(x => x.Conclusao != "PRÓPRIO")
                            .GroupBy(x => x.Representante)
                            .Select(x => new DetalhesExcel
                            {
                                NumColunaInicial = 23,
                                Coluna1 = x.First().Representante,
                                Coluna2 = x.Sum(y => y.ValorRepasse).ToString(),
                                Coluna3 = x.Sum(y => y.KmRepasse).ToString()
                            }).ToList());

    }
}

public class Ocorrencia
{
    public string Conclusao { get; set; }
    public string Representante { get; set; }
    public int KmRepasse { get; set; }
    public int ValorRepasse { get; set; }
}

public class DetalhesExcel
{
    public int NumColunaInicial { get; set; }
    public string Coluna1 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna2 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna3 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna4 { get; set; }
    public string Coluna5 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Taian nice, i'm glad to help

Answer (score 1):

`AddRange` returns void. Thus seperate List initialization and `AddRange` into two.

```
Detalhes = new List<DetalhesExcel>() {
    new DetalhesExcel()
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = "Representante",
        Coluna2 = "ValorRepasse",
        Coluna3 = "KmRepasse"
    }
};

Detalhes.AddRange(ocorrencias.Where(x => x.Conclusao != "PRÓPRIO")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Representante)
    .Select(x => new DetalhesExcel
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = x.First().Representante,
        Coluna2 = x.Sum(y => y.ValorRepasse).ToString(),
        Coluna3 = x.Sum(y => y.KmRepasse).ToString()
    }).ToList())
```

Comment: There's no way to "merge" them? "Detalhes" is a property of another object and I don't want so separate it.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`AddRange`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiTif-DrM3gAhWRHzQIHdsGDk8QFjABegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fdn456080(v%3Dvs.111).aspx&usg=AOvVaw1XAKuVM7f7xtIQ1zwjCMve) modifies the existing sequence and returns `void`, it cannot be used in a method chain as part of an assignment. However, you can use the [`Concat`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwix9LGkrM3gAhUpwFQKHQ87C-QQFjAAegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.linq.enumerable.concat&usg=AOvVaw2UBrfnhNbDr77ny-_RdmMP) method, which creates a new sequence by concatenating the first with the second, and then returns that new sequence:

```
Detalhes = new List<DetalhesExcel>()
{
    new DetalhesExcel()
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = "Representante",
        Coluna2 = "ValorRepasse",
        Coluna3 = "KmRepasse"
    }
}.Concat(ocorrencias.Where(x => x.Conclusao != "PRÓPRIO")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Representante)
    .Select(x => new DetalhesExcel
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = x.First().Representante,
        Coluna2 = x.Sum(y => y.ValorRepasse).ToString(),
        Coluna3 = x.Sum(y => y.KmRepasse).ToString()
    }).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

`AddRange()` returns `void` and that' the final method you are applying on your `list`.
You cannot assign that to a `list`.

```
Detalhes = new List<DetalhesExcel>() {
    new DetalhesExcel()
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = "Representante",
        Coluna2 = "ValorRepasse",
        Coluna3 = "KmRepasse"
    }
};
Detalhes.AddRange(ocorrencias.Where(x => x.Conclusao != "PRÓPRIO")
        .GroupBy(x => x.Representante)
        .Select(x => new DetalhesExcel
        {
            NumColunaInicial = 23,
            Coluna1 = x.First().Representante,
            Coluna2 = x.Sum(y => y.ValorRepasse).ToString(),
            Coluna3 = x.Sum(y => y.KmRepasse).ToString()
        }).ToList())
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment on Simonare's answer that you made, have you tried doing

```
Detalhes = new List<DetalhesExcel>(ocorrencias.Where(x => x.Conclusao != "PRÓPRIO")
    .GroupBy(x => x.Representante)
    .Select(x => new DetalhesExcel
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = x.First().Representante,
        Coluna2 = x.Sum(y => y.ValorRepasse).ToString(),
        Coluna3 = x.Sum(y => y.KmRepasse).ToString()
    }).ToList())
    {
    new DetalhesExcel()
    {
        NumColunaInicial = 23,
        Coluna1 = "Representante",
        Coluna2 = "ValorRepasse",
        Coluna3 = "KmRepasse"
    }
    };
```

essentially using the selected list in the list based constructor